# How to redirect to another JSP after getting success result using Ajax call in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts 2 to register a user.

I am using Ajax call to register a user, after getting register I am able to get the success message in success function at Ajax call.  But its not getting redirect to other JSP based on `struts.xml` result `type=success`.

**`register.jsp`:**

```
<s:form id="form">
     <s:textfield name="email" id="email" label="Email" required="true" onkeyup="loadXMLDoc()" onblur="userNameCheck()"></s:textfield>
     <s:textfield name="mobile" id="mobile" label="Mobile"></s:textfield>
     <s:textfield name="username" id="username" readonly="true"
      label="Username"></s:textfield>
     <s:textfield name="first_name" id="first_name"
      label="First Name"></s:textfield>
     <s:textfield name="last_name" id="last_name"
      label="Last Name"></s:textfield>
     <s:password name="password" id="password" label="Password"></s:password>
     <s:password name="uconfirm_password" id="confirm_password"
      label="Confirm"></s:password>
     <div class="button">
      <input type="reset" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel">
      <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
     </div>
    </s:form>
```

**Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({ // Ajax function to call the action 
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    url : 'user',
    dataType : "html",
    data : registerFormToJSON(),
    success : function(html) {
        alert("Successfully Registered");

    },//End of success function in ajax call

    error : function(err) {

        console.log("Fail");
        return true;
    } //End of error function in ajax call
});
return false;
}
});


function registerFormToJSON() {

    var data = JSON.stringify({

        "userbean" : {
            "username" : $("#username").val(),
            "password" : $("#password").val(),
            "firstname" : $("#first_name").val(),
            "lastname" : $("#last_name").val(),
            "confirmpassword" : $("#confirm_password").val(),
            "email" : $("#email").val(),
            "mobile" : $("#mobile").val(),

        }

    }); //End of getting form values and storing in json variable
    alert(data);
    return data;

}//End of function registerFormToJSON()
```

**Action Class Method:**

```
public class UserController implements Action {
    private UserBeans userbean;

    /**
     * @return the userbean
     */
    public UserBeans getUserbean() {
        return userbean;
    }

    /**
     * @param userbean
     *            the userbean to set
     */
    public void setUserbean(UserBeans userbean) {
        this.userbean = userbean;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String register() {
        UserService service = new UserServiceImpl();
        userbean = service.addorUpDateUser(userbean);
        // response.setContentType("json");
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**DAO Class method:**

```
public UserBeans addOrUpdateUser(UserBeans userBean) {
    properties.load(inputStream);
    con = conn.createConnection();
    System.out.println("name is mine" + userBean.getUsername());
    String encryptedPassword = PasswordUtil.encryptPassword(userBean.getPassword());
    String query = properties.getProperty("users_query");
    System.out.println(query);
    System.out.println("connection:" + con);
    preparedstatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedstatement.setString(1, userBean.getUsername());
    preparedstatement.setString(2, encryptedPassword);
    preparedstatement.setString(3, userBean.getEmail());
    preparedstatement.setString(4, userBean.getFirstname());
    preparedstatement.setString(5, userBean.getLastname());
    preparedstatement.setString(6, userBean.getMobile());
    preparedstatement.setString(7, userBean.getConfirmpassword());
    preparedstatement.executeUpdate(); // execute insert statement
    logger.info("UserDaoImpl  addOrUpDate Ends");
    return userBean;
}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="," />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default"
        namespace="/">
        <action name="users" class="com.sample.controller.UserController"
            method="register">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="json">
                <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success" type="json">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `login` action in the `default` package which returns a `login.jsp` as a result.

```xml
<action name="login">
   <rerult>/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

on success handler use the code

```javascript
success : function(html) {
    alert("Successfully Registered");
    window.location = '<s:url namespace="/" action="login"/>';

},//End of success function in ajax call
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to go on different page on successful registration why are you using ajax?

Because main use of ajax is to load data without refresh but here you are sending user to next page that means result page is going to reload; then why to use ajax for such situation?.

So better way is to use normal Struts2 action call.

And one suggestion is use `('formId').serialize()` or `('formId').serializeArray()` method to get form parameters instead of getting each parameter by `id`.

Answer (score -2):

I agree the above answer by [Roman C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/roman-c) , If you want to redirect your page, don't use ajax call, just submit your form normally and it will redirect you to the jsp you have declared in struts.xml.